# linked list beginning and end in python

Tags: python, list, linked-list

here my question is i have a linked list of 1->2->3->4->5

my concept is to print them like 1->5->2->4->3

it means first beginning and then end

how can i do it?

i have an idea that is first i take a empty node in empty node i will keep beginning node and

after that i will traverse to last and end node will be kept there at this my brain stops

can anyone guide me to do this? thanks in advance

```
def mutate_linked_list(head):
   #node creation
   s = t = Node()
   t.next = head
   head = head.next
   while head is None:
        t.next = head
        head = head.next
        # here i used recursion concept
        mutate_linked_list(head)
  return head
```

but it is not working....

Comment: do you HAVE to use a linked list? linked lists perform horribly when doing random access. A doubly linked list might be a better option (for your case).

Comment: More to the point, do you have a reason not to use Python's built-in list type?

Comment: This is not the pythonic way. Don't do it like this, use a list.

Answer (score 2):

```
[head[0]]+[head[-1]] + head[1:-1]
```

Comment: can you write the full code please thanks in advance?

Comment: @pradeepkumar: This is full code assuming `head = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: This would be better written `head[:1] + head[-1:] + head[1:-1]` IMO

Comment: But this solution does return `[1,5,2,3,4]` while the expected output according to OP would be `[1,5,2,4,3]`

Answer (score 0):

```
def mutate_linked_list(head):
    # return early for an size 1 list
    if head.next is None:
        return head

    # find the last and penultimate nodes
    penultimate = head
    while penultimate.next.next is not None:
        penultimate = penultimate.next
    last = penultimate.next

    # detach the last node from the end
    penultimate.next = None

    # prepend it to the second node
    last.next = head.next.next

    # and reconnect the head
    head.next = last

    return head
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import deque
def mutate_linked_list(head):
   mydeque = deque(head)
   try:
     while True:
       yield mydeque.popleft()
       yield mydeque.pop()
   except IndexError:
     pass

for i in mutate_linked_list(range(1,6)):
  print(i)
```

You can obviously do a list and .append to it instead of yielding values.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an exercise ...

```
def mix(head):
    # Walk to the end of the list
    last = head
    secondlast = None
    while last.next:
        secondlast = last
        last = last.next

    if secondlast:
         # move last element to second place
         secondlast.next = None
         last.next = head.next
         head.next = last

         # mix the rest of the list (recursion)
         mix(last.next)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def mutate_linked_list(head):
    m = len(head)/2 # Get the middle position
    return [item for pair in izip_longest(head[:m+1], head[:m:-1])
                 for item in pair
                 if item is not None]
```

An then, you're ready  to go:

```
head = [1,2,3,4,5]
mutate_linked_list(head)

[1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
```

It also works with lists with even number of elements...

```
head = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
mutate_linked_list(head)

[1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4]
```